# ERROR while using " pip install catboost " : Failed building wheel for catboost

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, jupyter, catboost

I'm trying to install the catboost package through a requirements.txt file in my virtual environment, but while building the wheel for catboost (pyproject.toml), an error occurs.

Environment:

- Python: 3.9.0
- pip: 23.2.1
- Version: 6.25.2
- Summary: IPython Kernel for Jupyter

```
Building wheels for collected packages: catboost
Building wheel for catboost (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Building wheel for catboost (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
[97 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/monoforest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/plot_helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/metrics.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/text_processing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/datasets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
copying catboost/dev_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/widget
copying catboost/widget/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/widget
copying catboost/widget/metrics_plotter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/widget
copying catboost/widget/ipythonwidget.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/widget
copying catboost/widget/callbacks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/widget
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/catboost_evaluation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/_fold_model.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/_readers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/log_config.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/_splitter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/execution_case.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/_fold_storage.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/factor_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/evaluation_result.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
copying catboost/eval/_fold_models_handler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/catboost/eval
running build_ext
Buildling _catboost with cmake and ninja
target_platform=darwin-x86_64. Building targets _catboost with PIC
Running "cmake /private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/catboost_all_src -B /private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39 -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/catboost_all_src/build/toolchains/clang.toolchain --log-level=VERBOSE -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=On -DCATBOOST_COMPONENTS=python-package -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0 -DHAVE_CUDA=no -DPython3_ROOT_DIR=/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/DataScienceProject/venv"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/DataScienceProject/venv/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
from cmake import cmake
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/DataScienceProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/DataScienceProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/DataScienceProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
return self._build_with_temp_dir(
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
self.run_setup()
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "<string>", line 723, in <module>
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
return run_commands(dist)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
dist.run_commands()
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "<string>", line 389, in run
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
self.run_command("build")
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "<string>", line 324, in run
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-build-env-2j5hlds4/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "<string>", line 436, in run
File "<string>", line 454, in build_with_cmake_and_ninja
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/catboost_all_src/build/build_native.py", line 517, in build
cmd_runner.run(cmake_cmd, env=build_environ)
File "/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/catboost_all_src/build/build_native.py", line 164, in run
subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, **subprocess_run_kwargs)
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/DataScienceProject/venv/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/catboost_all_src', '-B', '/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39', '-G', 'Ninja', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/private/var/folders/b3/szy3l0nj1dl6l88_mrmx68yc0000gp/T/pip-install-m3ncbhfq/catboost_0be2f62d1502408eaae1006384df9f86/catboost_all_src/build/toolchains/clang.toolchain', '--log-level=VERBOSE', '-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=On', '-DCATBOOST_COMPONENTS=python-package', '-DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0', '-DHAVE_CUDA=no', '-DPython3_ROOT_DIR=/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/DataScienceProject/venv']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for catboost
Failed to build catboost
ERROR: Could not build wheels for catboost, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Which version of Catboost are you attempting to install? If it's too old, chances are there aren't prebuilt Python 3.9 wheels for your platform (and trying to build from scratch is hard)

Comment: I haven't defined any Catboost version in my requirements.txt. But I'll try by adding Catboost version.

Comment: Sure, but it would be useful to know which version you're trying to install nevertheless. Catboost 1.2.1.1 seems to have a py39 mac wheel: https://pypi.org/project/catboost/1.2.1.1/#files

Comment: I have tried 1.2.1.1 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost==1.2.1.1' so I tried version 1.2 . But still the same issue.

Comment: So here i how i solved it: Updated python version = 3.10.9 . Downgraded catboost version from 1.2.1 to 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

### I successfully installed by re-install my Anaconda.

I recently encountered a similar issue.

My goal was to install `catboost` but stumbled when building the wheel for CatBoost.

For your reference, my MacBook and Environment are as below:

- **MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2019 (Intel Processor)**
- **macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 (23B92)**
- **Anaconda** version 2.4.1 (Failed to update to the current version 2.5.1)
- **pip** version 23.2.1
- **Python** version 3.10

Here's a breakdown of the challenges I faced and the steps I took to resolve them:

#### Initial Update Attempts

1. **Updating Conda via Terminal**: My first attempt to update Conda through the terminal failed. I used:

   ```bash
   conda update --all
   ```

Unfortunately, this did not work as expected.

2. **Updating via Anaconda Navigator**: Next, I tried updating through Anaconda Navigator, but encountered a `MultiError`.

#### Solution: Fresh Anaconda Installation

Due to these issues, I decided to perform a fresh installation of Anaconda.

1. **Backup Anaconda3**: I started by backing up my existing Anaconda environment:

   ```bash
   conda env export > environment.yml
   ```
2. **Remove Existing Anaconda Installation**: Next, I removed the existing Anaconda installation to avoid conflicts:

   ```bash
   rm -rf ~/anaconda3
   ```
3. **Download and Install Anaconda**: I then downloaded the latest Anaconda Installer from the [Anaconda Distribution page](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) and executed a fresh installation.
4. **Update Anaconda to 2.5.1**: After reinstalling, I updated Anaconda to the latest version by using Anaconda Navigator.

#### Installing CatBoost

1. **Initial CatBoost Installation Attempt**: Initially, I tried installing catboost using pip, but encountered the same wheel build failure:

   ```bash
   pip install catboost
   ```

This led to a "Failed to Build wheel for catboost (pyproject.toml)" error.

2. **Successful CatBoost Installation**: Finally, I successfully installed catboost using Conda:

   ```bash
   conda install -c conda-forge catboost
   ```

#### Conclusion

Performing a fresh installation of Anaconda, followed by updating to the latest version and using Conda to install `catboost`, resolved the issues I encountered. This method could be beneficial for anyone facing similar challenges with updating Anaconda or installing specific packages on macOS.